# SQL: Get all posts with any comments

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to construct some rather simple SQL, I suppose, but as it's a rare event that I work with DBs these days I can't figure out the details.

I have a table 'posts' with the following columns:

> id, caption, text

and a table 'comments' with the following columns:

> id, name, text, post_id

What would the (single) SQL statement look like which retrieves the captions of all posts which have one or more comments associated with it through the 'post_id' key? The DBMS is MySQL if it has any relevance for the SQL query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select p.caption, count(c.id)
from posts p join comments c on p.id = c.post_id
group by p.caption
having count (c.id) > 0
```

Comment: the HAVING and COUNT is unnessesacry since he want anything that has 1 OR more comments. and use INNER JOIN for clarity, even though inner join is the default.

Comment: and GROUP BY p.id instead, since that will probably the primary key.

Comment: It should be "... > 0" rather than "... > 1", other than that it's looking good :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.caption, p.id
    FROM posts p, 
         comments c 
    WHERE c.post_ID = p.ID
```

I think using a join would be a lot faster than using the IN clause or a subquery.

Comment: I'm not sure if DISTINCT would work here, or if I'd have to nest it into a subquery ie, SELECT DISTINCT Caption FROM (my query)...but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: I believe distinct would work here since caption and p.id would be equal for each post.

Comment: We are probably right, but I don't have time to play with it on a DB. I'll remove my caveat anyways =)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT caption FROM posts 
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id 
GROUP BY posts.id;
```

No need for a `having` clause or `count()`.

edit: Should be a `inner join` of course (to avoid nulls if a comment is orphaned), thanks to jishi.

Comment: that one would give him null posts for orphaned comments, which is a bad idea. a left join would give nulls for comments. An inner join is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT caption
FROM posts
    INNER JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id
```

Forget about counts and subqueries.

The inner join will pick up all the comments that have valid posts and exclude all the posts that have 0 comments.  The DISTINCT will coalesce the duplicate caption entries for posts that have more then 1 comment.

Comment: Does MySQL not have the inferred inner join syntax (look at my post below that is T-SQL)

Answer (score 0):

I find this syntax to be the most readable in this situation:

```
SELECT * FROM posts P 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE post_id = P.id)
```

It expresses your intent better than most of the others in this thread - "give me all the posts ..." (select * from posts) "... that have any comments" (where exist (select * from comments ... )). It's essentially the same as the joins above, but because you're not actually doing a join, you don't have to worry about getting duplicates of the records in Posts, so you'll just get one record per post.

Comment: You have also posted the slowest query yet =)

Comment: Hmm ... I think that depends on the DB engine. The query isn't *inherently* slower, because it is relationally equivalent to a join. A good optimizer should run this just as fast as a join, or faster if it can avoid materializing the join results for the distinct. Course, I haven't tested it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Just going off the top of my head here but maybe something like:

```
SELECT caption FROM posts WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id FROM comments HAVING count(*) > 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

You're basically looking at performing a subquery --

`SELECT p.caption FROM posts p WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.post_id=p.id) > 1;`

This has the effect of running the `SELECT COUNT(*)` subquery for each row in the posts table. Depending on the size of your tables, you might consider adding an additional column, `comment_count`, into your `posts` table to store the number of corresponding `comments`, such that you can simply do

`SELECT p.caption FROM posts p WHERE comment_count > 1`

Comment: Nooo! Denormilization should never be advocated on something this simple.